# How to use react build websites without using react-router ?

Tags: django, facebook, reactjs, react-router

I'm building a website with Django and react, and since Django itself has a routing system, and I don't want to discard that, so I decide not to use javascript routing libraries.

I'm using webpack to bundle my files, but since I'm not using react router, there's a lot of webpack entry files, and a lot of bundled files (almost one per page), and I'm not sure if this is a 'correct' way.

And since there's one javascript file per page, the states or other things between different pages are not shared, every page is independent of each other. Can I have some 'shared' things without using react-router?

I know Facebook itself and Airbnb don't use react-router either, so how do they use react? How do they handle a lot of bundled files?

Can anyone work for a company that does not use react-router share your company's solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to accomplish this is in the same way as you do it using vanilla javascript or some library like jQuery.

You don't manage a `state` in the front end, you grab the state server side and you put it in the HTML and then you use it with javascript.

React.js isn't different and if you're using [redux](http://redux.js.org) you could put that data directly in the initial state of every page/section of your whole webpage.

Answer (score 0):

<>

Yes. But in order to share in the way you imagine, you *do* have to make your app single paged. That is, you don't link around to different URL's. Any view change would change at most the #anchor part of the URL, but needn't do anything to the URL - just use Javascript logic to change what component(s) get rendered. As long as the base part of your URL stays on the same page, your shared objects will stick around.